# Java GUI App Cant Send Mail with .exe setup file

Tags: java, user-interface, jakarta-mail

I'm working on an application using (JAVA GUI), and this application has a feature to send mails to customers. problem is i am build my app to (.jar) and every thing works fine but now i want to use this app on another computer ,so i convert (.jar) to (.exe setup file) using (Excelsior JET) and also everything works fine except sending mail i dont know why ?.
Lib used > javamail,smtp,dsn,pop3,imap,mailapi )

Comment: What does the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) show?  I don't know how Excelsior JET creates the .exe file but if it extracts the contents of the JavaMail jar file, or uses its own class loader, it may not be finding the JavaMail configuration files.

Comment: Must be a configuration problem. Reach out to our techsupport (java at excelsior-usa.com).